# SQL Generate Script Not Creating Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a script of my database.

But When I run it, the script does not create the database. It skips the "Create db" statement, and only creates the tables (on the database I have selected at the moment, so not ideal....)

(query executes with no errors by the way.)

Why is this happening? why cant you create a database and edit the content in it in one go?

(I know you can check if the db exist first, but this shouldn't be happening from the start)

--My Script--

```
CREATE DATABASE [EthicsDB] 

USE [EthicsDB]
go

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempEmployee](
    [PersonnelNumber] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [SurName] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [ManagerEmail] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [ManagerName] [varchar](80) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TempEmployee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonnelNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use GO after CREATE DATABASE [EthicsDB].

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
USE [master]
GO

IF  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'EthicsDB'
)
DROP DATABASE [EthicsDB]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [EthicsDB]
GO --<----

USE [EthicsDB]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempEmployee](
    [PersonnelNumber] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [SurName] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [ManagerEmail] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [ManagerName] [varchar](80) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TempEmployee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonnelNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run the SQL as provided you get an error message on the line

```
USE [EthicsDB]
```

This occurs as when SQL Servers runs SQL commands via SQL CMD it process the SQL in batches.

As you have no GO statement after the Create database statement it maybe that SQL Server does not yet recognise that a new database Ethics has been created and thus when you attempt to use the database via USE [EthicsDB] the statement fails.

As your SQL Statements are not wrapped in a transaction and as you are not checking for errors then if  SQL Server encounters an error it will raise the error but also continue to process the rest of the query.

In the query provided this leads to the new tables being created in the current database.

To correct the problem modify your query to

```
CREATE DATABASE [EthicsDB] 
go
USE [EthicsDB]
go
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably wrap each action in a transaction block.

Also, when you are creating the table I generally do a check to see if it already exists first.

If you run **only** the create database, what happens?